# Noisy numerical finite difference calculated by NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative

Tags: finite-difference-method

I met a problem when playing with the numerical difference provided by mathematica. My aim is to test the accuracy of the high-order numerical derivative. The code is below

```
Nx = 512; u0 = 0; uN = 5.0; du = (uN - u0)/Nx; ugrid = du Range[0, Nx];
C0 = Sin[Pi #/uN] & /@ ugrid;
order = 3;
der = 6;
exact1 = D[Sin[u Pi/uN], {u, der}];
exact2 = Table[
   exact1, {u, ugrid[[1]], ugrid[[-1]], ugrid[[2]] - ugrid[[1]]}];
num = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[der], ugrid, C0, 
   "DifferenceOrder" -> order];
ListPlot[{Transpose[{ugrid, exact2}], Transpose[{ugrid, num}]}]
```

The result looks like this
[image]

However, when I place the code in a dynamic module to play with the order of derivatives and number of points

```
Manipulate[Nx=2^pow;u0=0;uN=5;du=(uN-u0)/Nx;
ugrid=du Range[0,Nx];
C0=Sin[Pi #/uN]& /@ugrid;
exact1=D[Sin[Pi u/uN],{u,der}];
exact2=Table[exact1,{u,ugrid[[1]],ugrid[[-1]],ugrid[[2]]-ugrid[[1]]}];
num=NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[der],ugrid,C0,"DifferenceOrder"->order];
ListPlot[{Transpose[{ugrid,exact2}],Transpose[{ugrid,num}]}],{{pow,9,Dynamic["Points: "<>ToString[2^pow]]},4,15,1},{{order,3,Dynamic["Order: "<>ToString[order]]},1,15,1},{{der,6,Dynamic["Deriv: "<>ToString[der]]},1,18,1},ContinuousAction->False,LabelStyle->"Text"]
```

The result looks pretty good
[image]

I'm not sure what the dynamic module does such that they generate different results with the normal one.

Comment: I also posted the question to mathematica community https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1793359?p_p_auth=6EJj28fA

Comment: Because the `uN` is different in both cases…

Comment: Thank you. I didn't expect 5 and 5.0 make such a big difference! Do you know if there is a way to improve the results for 5.0?

Comment: You can turn to arbitrary precision e.g. ``uN = 5`16``.

Comment: "To test" the accuracy and "to improve" the accuracy seem different goals.  Why would you want to improve the 5.0 case, if that is the use case you wish to test?

Comment: @xzczd, thank you. It works!

Comment: @MichaelE2. Yes. I'm dealing with a more complicated numerical problem. This is just a minor part of it. I had to do it numerically.